# Is it possible to find the database a stored procedure was called from?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Imagine I have a procedure in database A on SQL Server 2008R2+.

```
USE A
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.My_Test
AS 
BEGIN
    PRINT ORIGINAL_DB_NAME()
    PRINT DB_NAME()
END
GO
```

Now I call that procedure while in database B.

```
USE B
GO

EXEC A.dbo.My_Test
```

It will return this:

```
A
A
```

ORIGINAL_DB_NAME() gives you the default database from your login if there is one. In this case it's A but it could be anything, it's not the most recent/current/super-context database.

Now imagine in My_Test you want to do a RESTORE DATABASE B. This works if you called it while you were in master or A, but fails with an error if you were in B (because that database is in use).

```
Msg 3102, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
RESTORE cannot process database 'B' because it is in use by this session. It is recommended that the master database be used when performing this operation.
```

I am planning to catch and handle that exception, but I found the problem interesting as there doesn't appear to be a way to "discover" that you were in B ahead of time. And you can't do a USE master in the procedure to avoid the problem either (use statements aren't valid in procedures).

Is it possible to find that you were in database B ahead of time?

Answer (score 1):

1/ Send DB name as parameter to  your stored proc

or

2/ To make SP run in the context of current connection you need create your SP on master database and make it a system object.

```
USE MASTER 
GO 

-- name should start with "sp_"
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_My_Test
@OriginalDB SYSNAME
AS 
BEGIN
    PRINT ORIGINAL_DB_NAME()
    PRINT DB_NAME()
END
GO

EXEC sp_ms_marksystemobject 'sp_My_Test'
GO

USE Test2
GO

EXEC master..sp_My_Test @OriginalDB = DB_NAME
```